# HTTP Bearer with Sessions and subdomains

Tags: session-cookies, restful-authentication, passport.js

I am trying to build a single page web-application that can be accessed at client.domain.com. I have webservice apis exposed at api.domain.com (accessed by mobile app clients as well).

Using passport I have implemented Local,Basic and Bearer authentication strategies. They seem to work well when testing with curl.

While supplying 'access_token' in the API call works well for mobile and curl, it is going to be painful to implement for Javascript web client. I am thinking of storing the access_token in the session/cookie. Does this make sense or will it compromise security?

I am hoping to achieve the following:
User access client.domain.com. A login form is presented which submits to api.domain.com/token. On successful authentication, I want to send a token in a session/cookie. All subsequent requests to api.domina.com will automatically use sessions.

If this seems alright, how do I get this to work -- token will be read from sessions and Bearer authentication will work without having to append access_token as query parameter.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serializeUser: " + JSON.stringify(user));
  done(null, "1234");
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(token, done) {
    console.log("deserializeUser:"+ token);
    // trying to set a parameter in the req object
    done(null, {access_token:token});
});
```